# Environment variable ANDROID_HOME is not set

Tags: android, cordova

Environment variable ANDROID_HOME is not set while it is set in .bashrc. Please help me to resolve this problem. One more issue is occurring is that i need run each cordova command with sudo. e.g. if i want to run create command than i need to write "sudo cordova create xyz com.xyz.abc" instead of "cordova create xyz com.xyz.abc"
Here is my screen of terminal. Please check it[image: Please open this image for my terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Don't prefix `cordova build android` with `sudo`, then the environment variable will be available.
You should not ever need to use `sudo` with `cordova` anyway.

Comment: yes i did this but it shows error if i dont prefix sudo. It shows error that "EACCESS" for file in .config folder of home directory

Comment: by the way i have resolve this problem by installing cordova by NVM. but still this problem is arising while i am not using sudo.

Comment: Which file exactly? You probably created this file when you ran one of the initial commands with `sudo`. Remove it, and it should be recreated with the correct access rights.